# How to use multi conditions in WHILE loop?

Tags: c#, while-loop

I am trying to use OR condition in C# in WHILE loop, but it doesn't work :( if I do separate conditions without OR conditions then it works!

it works like this:

```
while (myAnswer.ToLower() != "yes")
{
    Console.Write("Please write YES or NO!: ");
    myAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

but if I try to add additional conditions, doesnt metter its AND or OR, it sends me to infinite loop. For example this doesnt work:

```
while ((myAnswer.ToLower() != "yes") || (myAnswer.ToLower() != "no"))
{
    Console.Write("Please write YES or NO!: ");
    myAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: `(myAnswer.ToLower() != "yes") || (myAnswer.ToLower() != "no")` will _always_ be true. You need `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: Please write your logic, because OR in your condition create a loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you want exit from your while if user writes YES or NO, your condition will be:

In other words, you repeat the question until the response will be YES or NO.

```
while ((myAnswer.ToLower() != "yes") && (myAnswer.ToLower() != "no"))
{
    Console.Write("Please write YES or NO!: ");
    myAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
}
```